# Why does setting the primaryAction property of a UIBarButtonItem change its image?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

**Edit: This is resolved, see bottom of post.**

I'm looking to set a `primaryAction` for a `UIBarButtonItem` *after* I've initialized the button with the [`init(title:image:primaryAction:menu:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/3600776-init) convenience initializer.

When I do this, the image property gets `nil`'d out, like so:

```swift
let settingsButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: nil, image: gearImage, primaryAction: nil, menu: nil)

// Before - settingsButton.image is non-nil, as expected
settingsButton.primaryAction = UIAction(...)

// After - settingsButton.image is nil - unexpected
```

Looking at the UIKit header documentation, I noticed this:

```
/// Set the primaryAction on this item, updating the title & image of the item if appropriate 
(primaryAction is non-nil, and this is not a system item). 
When primaryAction is non-nil, the target & action properties are ignored. 
If primaryAction is set to nil, the title & image properties are left unchanged.
```

> Set the primaryAction on this item, updating the title & image of the item if appropriate

So I think this event is causing the `image` to be nil, but...why would this trigger? What is the purpose?

I can get around this by setting the `image` property after setting the `primaryAction`, such that:

```swift
let settingsButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: nil, image: gearImage, primaryAction: nil, menu: nil)

settingsButton.primaryAction = UIAction(...)
settingsButton.image = gearImage
```

But this effectively makes the convenience initializer useless in this case.

---

Edit: Thanks to @Sweeper for pointing this out. The `UIBarButtonItem` seems to use the `title` and `image` from a `UIAction` to update its image and title then the `primaryAction` property is set.

You can create a `UIAction` with the [`init(title:image:identifier:discoverabilityTitle:attributes:state:handler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaction/3358590-init) initializer and pass in your image into that action in order for it to render, like so:

```swift
settingsButton.primaryAction = UIAction(title: "", 
                                        image: gearImage, 
                                        identifier: nil, 
                                        discoverabilityTitle: nil, 
                                        attributes: .disabled, 
                                        state: .mixed, handler: { (action) in
    // Do something here
})
```

Because in my case, I was using the `UIAction(handler:)` initializer, this will set the `UIAction`'s `title` and `image` property nil, which causes the `UIBarButtonItem`'s image to become nil.

Comment: Do you understand that `UIAction`s also have an image and title? If you set `settingsButton.primaryAction = someAction`, it would make sense for `settingsButton` to have the same image as `someAction`, wouldn't it?

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Specifying the image in the UIAction resolves this. Thanks @Sweeper.